# Angular function in controller not getting called after promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building an Angular 1.5 app using the component structure. After the promise comes back from the $http call in the service, I am trying to call another function to filter the dataset before it is displayed on the UI.

However, the filterApps function is not getting called.

Also...in the filterApps function I am trying to compare to arrays of objects and return back the ones that have the same name. Is this the best way to go about this or is there a cleaner way?

Controller :

```
import allApps from '../../resources/data/application_data.js';

class HomeController {
    /*@ngInject*/
    constructor(ItemsService) {
        this.itemsService = ItemsService;
        this.displayApps = [];
    }

    $onInit() {
        this.itemsService
            .getItems()
            .success((apps) => this.filterApps(apps));
    }

    filterApps(siteApps) {
        this.displayApps = allApps.applications.filter((app) => {
            siteApps.applications.map((siteApp) => {
                if(siteApp.name === app.name) {
                    return app;
                }
            })
        });
    }
}

export default HomeController;
```

Comment: I don't see any `$http` call...

Comment: Does it really get into success callback, try adding `.error((error) => console.log(error))`? Are you sure `getItems` does return a promise.. check console as well for error

Comment: @DannyBuonocore the $http call is in a service which has nothing to do with the question

Comment: @PankajParkar yes it does go into the success callback. Previously I had `this.itemsService
            .getItems()
            .success((apps) => this.displayApps = apps);` and all the apps were displayed

Comment: You'd be surprised how many questions on here can't be answered because the the OP thought the offending code "had nothing to do with the question"... just sayin'

Comment: @DannyBuonocore I understand, however the $http.get call is working fine and I am able to set `this.displayApps = apps` in the success callback. It's just not calling the filterApps function

Comment: How do you know filterapps isnt being called, you're not doing anything with it?

Comment: @DanielKobe yes, you're correct, he missed to debug. look at mine answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason that `filterApps` method isn't geting call(as you already commented that `success` function is getting called). I guess you're just checking nothing has been carried in `displayApps` variable. The real problem  is you have not return internal `map` function result to `filter`. So that's why nothing gets return.

**Code**

```
filterApps(siteApps) {
    this.displayApps = allApps.applications.filter((app) => {
        //returning map function result.
        return siteApps.applications.map((siteApp) => {
            if(siteApp.name === app.name) {
                return app;
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was missing that return. Also is there a better way to do that array comparison?

Comment: @erichardson30 it seems correct to me.. as you are comparing `name` of an object for equality.